# how to substract the two columns to have the time difference between them in new column using bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to make new column with time difference only.
started_at  ended_at
2020-01-21 20:06:59 2020-01-21 20:14:30
2020-01-30 14:22:39 2020-01-30 14:26:22
2020-01-09 19:29:26 2020-01-09 19:32:17
2020-01-06 16:17:07 2020-01-06 16:25:56
2020-01-30 8:37:16  2020-01-30 8:42:48
2020-01-10 12:33:05 2020-01-10 12:37:54
2020-01-10 13:07:35 2020-01-10 13:12:24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, SECOND) AS duration_seconds
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff